# onActivityResult always returns 0 (RESULT_CANCELED) when calling settings

Tags: android, android-activity

I might be approaching the problem in a wrong way..

What I'm doing is showing an alert message when there is no internet connection and the "ok" button leads the user to the wifi setting to turn on the internet. What I want the application to do, when the user returns to it after changing (or not) the internet settings is to reload the application or activity where it was.

For this I am doing the following call for the "ok" button:

```
 static void startAct(Activity ctxt)
{
    ctxt.startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), WIFI_SETTINGS);

}
```

on the activity's class, where this message is shown I have the following:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == WIFI_SETTINGS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
     {
         this.finish();

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
     }
}
```

but resultCode is always 0, onActivityResult gets called right after the "ok" button is pressed.

Should I approach this problem differently? How can I reload/refresh my app when the user comes back from the wifi settings?

I have checked similar answers but they seem to use an activity within the same app, so they can call `set_result(...)`, but I can't do that here.

thanks!

Comment: Why not just check `onActivityResult`, if the wifi is now on. Regardless of what value it returns.

Comment: I could do that, but onActivityResult is called immediately after I press the "ok" button, so the user won't have time to change the settings before it gets called.

Comment: Which ok button? I thought you meant ok on the Wifi settings screen. Is the requestCode that returns the same as WIFI_SETTINGS?

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong intent there to launch it. You may wish to use Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS.

Comment: the ok buttons refers to the button of the alert message that I fire when there is no connection. The onClick method of that button calls startAct(this). Even if I change the settings that I open, I still have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said you should not call finish -- also calling `startActivityForResult` is not that helpful.  Even if the `resultCode` was other than 0, it takes a few seconds to connect to WiFi usually.

So to answer your question, you should use a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for network change intents.

This code is a bit old, but here is something similar I do in one of my apps.  It should hopefully get you started.

```
protected void registerWifiReceivers()
{   
    IntentFilter f1 = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    IntentFilter f2 = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION;
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, f1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, f2);       
}



final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{       
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
      String action = intent.getAction();        
      Log.d ( TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: " + action );

      if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
      {
         Log.i ( TAG, "handling event: WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION action: "+action );
         handleWifiStateChange(intent);
      }
      else if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) 
      {   
         Log.i ( TAG, "ignoring event: WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION action: "+action );
      } 
    }
}

protected void handleWifiStateChange ( Intent intent )
{   
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);      
    if (info.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
    {
        //do something...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

plesae don't use

```
          this.finish();
```

this will close your Activity completely. As you used startActivityForResult() method you should use this.finish after onActivityResult() method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new intent. Just do this -

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, as onActivityResult gets called right away and the resultCode is still the same: 0

Comment: in your case, startactivityforresults may not be very useful. You should instead just check on return if the wifi is now working and refresh the activity accordingly.